# Networkx multigraph not adding edges from another graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to take an undirected graph and convert it into a multigraph in networkx. Networkx offers multiple ways to do so however they all seem to be failing.

```
import networkx as nx

p = nx.complete_graph(3)
#p is the graph we'd like to convert into a multigraph

pMuti = nx.MultiGraph(incoming_graph_data=p)
print(nx.is_multigraphical(pMuti))
#output is false

pMuti = nx.MultiGraph()
for u,v in p.edges:
    pMulti.add_edge(u,v)
print(nx.is_multigraphical(pMuti))
#output is false

pMuti = nx.MultiGraph()
pMuti.add_edges_from(p.edges)
print(nx.is_multigraphical(pMuti))
#output is false
```

Welp let me know what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance.
==UPDATE==
The edge data in p is ([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)])
When adding edge data to all the edges in p via networkx's setedge attribute function:

```
attrs = {(u,v):{"randomKey":"val"} for (u,v) in p.edges}
nx.set_edge_attributes(p, attr)
pMuti = nx.MultiGraph(incoming_graph_data=p)
print(nx.is_multigraphical(pMuti))
#output is false
```

Even using Networkx's own reference on multigraph [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html) we still get a false on the is multigraph test (specifically using snippets from the example, nodes, and edges section).

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
H = nx.path_graph(10)
keys = G.add_edges_from(H.edges)
print(nx.is_multigraphical(G))
#output is false
```

However, if I explicitly add edges

```
q = nx.MultiGraph()
keys = q.add_edges_from([(1,2,{"attr1":1}), (1,3,{"attr2":2}),(3,2,{"attr3":3})])
#with or without attributes for each edge
print(nx.is_multigraphical(q))
#output is true
```

somehow the output is true.
Again, thanks in advance I know this is a long post.

Comment: Hi. Could you possibly update the question with a sample of the network data (in Graph p) so that we can work through the code? Also, what data will you be using to 'de-collapse' the network? It is normal to 'collapse' a network by turning a multigraph into a regular graph, but you will likely need edge attribute data to do the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph *is* a `MultiGraph` that has data from `p`.  For example, the following returns `True`:

```
isinstance(pMuti, nx.MultiGraph)
```

and you can inspect the edges of `pMuti` by calling `pMuti.edges` which returns, as expected:

```
MultiEdgeView([(0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (1, 2, 0)])
```

The problem is a misunderstanding of what [`nx.is_multigraphical()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.graphical.is_multigraphical.html#is-multigraphical) does.  It tests a sequence of integers representing node degrees for a property called "multigraphiness", but it does not test an object to see if it is a networkx `MultiGraph`.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying difference between those two functions. I still have a question though if anyone would be so kind as to help. Using the construction for p and q as defined in the above question, how come I get an error when I try to compose both graphs. Specifically,' r = nx.compose(p,q)' yields nx.NetworkXError("G and H must both be graphs or multigraphs."). This was my original question, but I thought it was a class difference.